# After edit of my htaccess file, my website returns 500 internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess

Before I describe my problem I'd like to let you know in advance that I've been searching regarding my problem for few hours already, but nothing has changed so far.

Now as of my problem, I do have a website that uses SSL but people can access it without the certificate, so I wanted to make changes to my htaccess file to force everyone to use SSL.

Originally my file looks like this

```
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
deny from IP
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
Options -Indexes

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 9M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 9M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

I just changed the file by putting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And then reuploaded the file, now my website returns 500 Internal Server Error.
Even tho if i remove the changes and upload the old one, the problem still remains. When i decided to check the error log, this is what I'm getting

> [Fri Dec 27 21:23:26.410830 2019] [core:alert] [pid 29752:tid 47333360273152] [client myIP:28351] /home/root/public_html/.htaccess: `</Files>` without matching `<Files>` section, referer: https://mywebsite.com/

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that there isn't a stray `#` symbol somewhere? This could be commenting out something, somewhere.

Comment: One thing that could have happened when you reuploaded it, is that the newline characters might not have worked as intended.

Comment: Hello, yes. As I haven't changed anything just added this snippet of 5 lines which resulted in this problem, decided to remove it and save the file as it was just like before but nothing.

Comment: I added another comment below my first. There are a few reasons why you're getting that error. I suggest you continue to Google this. I'd only be commenting back and forth.

Comment: Another thing that came to mind is how the file was saved, using which editor and if it did treat newline characters or not modify it at all; I've seen that happen before. If you're on a LINUX box and uploaded via Windows or vice-versa, then there may have been an incompatibility issue in encoding it. Check the file's encoding. That may not be included/mentioned in (your) Google findings. There also could be a hidden character or characters. You will need to be in HEX mode to see this for certain. Some things can happen in the background without knowing also.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response sir. I've just uploaded the file using FileZilla using the default editor (notepad). Do you believe additional new (empty) line would break the file ? If i completely remove the htaccess file I can access the website, but not the forum, because it requires those settings such as  php_value memory_limit 128M, and if they do not exist,  it cannot find the forum

Comment: Welcome. It's hard to say what FileZilla is doing, if it is doing something to modify something along the way. Try making a copy of your `.htaccess` and name it to `.htaccess_old`, then create a new one while making sure that there are newlines (ENTER)'s after each line and making sure nothing is commented out, because that's what the pound sign is, it's an htaccess comment character. Make sure it's saved as ANSI and not as UTF-8 and uploaded as TEXT and not BINARY.

Comment: Some FTP programs do not recognize `.htaccess` files and defaults to uploading in BINARY mode. If this is on your own computer, make sure you reboot/restart Apache. (sorry for the additional space here), it was too long and needed to be said/mentioned.

Comment: Hello, I've solved my problem using your method, did a copy of my .htaccess and just created a new one using sublime as an editor, uploaded thru FTP and now both of my pages are loading, the website and forum along with it. Huge thanks buddy, can my case be considered as solved ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreword: I used some of my comments to post this as a solution.

---

It appears that when uploading your file, that the entire file could be in one line and that a `#` comment character set itself in front of the opening `<Files>` tag.

Make a copy of your .htaccess and name it to `.htaccess_old`, then create a new one while making sure that there are newlines (ENTER)'s after each line and making sure nothing is commented out, because that's what the pound sign is, it's an `.htaccess` comment character.

Make sure it's saved as ANSI and not as UTF-8 and uploaded as TEXT and not BINARY. Saving as UTF-8 could cause it to embed a hidden BOM ([byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

Some FTP programs do not recognize `.htaccess` files as being a text file and defaults to uploading in BINARY mode; I know this from personal experience. If this is on your own computer, make sure you reboot/restart Apache.

In my experiences with `.htaccess` files, an 500 error will be thrown if the file was uploaded in BINARY mode instead of TEXT.

You can instruct certain FTP program to upload `.htaccess` files as TEXT.